# How to detect when cancel is clicked on save file dialog? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have a php-script that updates the download counter of the appropriate file (it sends headers with file). But if I click cancel button on save file dialog the counter is incremented too. It seems wrong.

My idea is to send ajax request and decrement counter if cancel button is clicked. But how to detect cancel button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using something like downloading with parts of the file using `fread` in PHP.

It looks like this:

```
// send file (it shows save file dialog)
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filepath));
header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$filename);
flush();

$file = fopen($filepath, "r");

while(!feof($file))
{
    // send the current file part to the browser
    print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));
    // flush the content to the browser
    flush();
    // sleep one second
    sleep(1);
}

// if all are right and file was downloaded
if (feof($file)) {
    update_current_counter_or_insert_new_one_in_DATABASE();
}

fclose($file);
```

This [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#83653) helps me to solve (php.net readfile article). So, it works for me more or less.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this [Track file download progress with Javascript](https://coolcodings.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/track-file-downloading-progress-with-javascript/) and do the increment when download 100% done